# My nostalgia dream

Tags: audio, music, mp3-player

I still remember to this day, my first ever MP3 player. It was a Matsui MAT101MR and I used to have it back in 2001. Problem is, I can't find one anywhere on ebay or anything. Does anyone know where I could get one?

Thx,
Depths :3

Comment: While I wasn't able to find one for sale, I did find an MP3 player by the name of Matsui mat110mr rather than mat101mr, which I'm guessing is just a typo.  This could give you a start on where to find one if you have the correct model number ;).  I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Salocor It IS the right model number: 101mr